# How I can restore deleted branch if I don't know revision?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I found such command

> svn cp svn://myrepo.com/svn/branches/2.0.5@4593 \
>          svn://myrepo.com/svn/branches/2.0.5_restored

where 4593 is revision number.

But I'm don't know the revision number before а branch deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted from [the manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.resurrect):

> A good strategy is to run svn log --verbose in a directory that used to contain
>   your deleted item. The --verbose (-v) option shows a list of all changed
>   items in each revision; all you need to do is find the revision in
>   which you deleted the file or directory.

For example:

```
svn log --verbose svn://myrepo.com/svn/branches | less
```